# HTML5 canvas/Jquery mousemove + mouseclick event

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas, mousemove, mouseclick-event, jquery-click-event

I'm trying to get a a simple interactive cannon that moves in a 180 degree arc which follows your mouse. And then, I want it to shoot cannonballs everytime you click anywhere on screen.

I'm using HTML5 canvas and/or jquery to do the job, so far I think that I should use a mousemove event, but I'm sure if that's the simplest way. But, on the other hand I could just get my cannon rotating constantly and set up a function that will point the cannon at a set of points, then just call that function every time you move the mouse. It's a scrappy idea, but I'm just stumped otherwise.

So far I drew my cannon in canvas as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/An3D8/1/

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var x = canvas.width / 2;
  var y = canvas.height / 1;
  var radius = 50;
  var startAngle = 1 * Math.PI;
  var endAngle = 2 * Math.PI;
  var counterClockwise = false;

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
  context.lineWidth = 15;

  // line color
  context.strokeStyle = 'black';
  context.stroke();
 </script>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(390, 400, 20, 70);
  context.fillStyle = 'grey';
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 7;
  context.strokeStyle = 'black';
  context.stroke();
</script>
```

What would be the simplest way to go about having to get the cannon to follow my mouse and then shoot cannonballs?

Comment: You'll need to calculate the angle between the center of the canon and the mouse position. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829010/find-angle-between-two-points-respective-to-horizontal-axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's Cryptoburner's link applied to your canon scenario:

http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/BE7F2/

Point your canon by listening for mousemove events:

- calculate the mouse position
- calculate the angle of the mouse versus your canon
- draw the canon to face the mouse position

Example mousemove code:

```
function handleMouseMove(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  var dx=mouseX-cx;
  var dy=mouseY-cy;
  var rAngle=Math.atan2(dy,dx);
  draw(rAngle-PI/2);
}
```

Shoot a canon ball at the mouse position by listening for mousedown events:

- calculate the mouse position
- draw you canon ball as a closed arc

Example mousedown code:

```
function handleMouseDown(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(mouseX,mouseY,12,0,PI*2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle="black";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.font="14px verdana";
  ctx.fillText("Bang!",mouseX-15,mouseY-20);
}
```